# Check if data arrived OK

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using the boost::asio (tcp) to send and receive fixed size (100bytes) data from one pc to another. What's the best way to check if everything arrived OK **without impacting performance?**

One idea is to save the first and last character and put them first, so: "hello my...battle in the end" will became "hd hello my...battle in the end". The final string will be 102 characters and the receiver can perform a size check also

another idea is to use a hash but i guess this will be very intense for the cpu

Do you guys have any good idea?

**NOTE:** Please keep in mind: i will use this millions of times, every microsecond counts.
The data are words separated by spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is designed to be a reliable transmission protocol.  Since you say you're using TCP, you can simply assume that if the data arrived and is of the full length, it arrived correctly.

If you're worried about data being corrupted in transmission beyond what TCP's 16-bit checksum can detect, you might add a 32-bit CRC to the end of your data.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that! Can disable the 16-bit checksum?

Comment: The checksum is an inherent part of the TCP protocol, so you can't.  If you're worried about performance, the checksum is designed to be very fast to calculate, and many network cards have hardware acceleration for it.

Comment: Just read the buffer as fast you can and process the fixed bytes. A delimiter would be a simple idea to check the end, use CRC only if required.